# GREATEST and split_part not working as intended in postgresqlp

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to run this query in pgadmin (postgresql) client but not getting expected response:

```
SELECT GREATEST(split_part('abc | 1 | 5', '|', 3), '0');
```

I expected the response to be 5 but it is 0. Am I missing anything?

PostgreSQL version is 13.7.

Comment: Works for me on 14.5. 1) What Postgres version? 2) What does `show lc_collate ;` return? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Your split_part as shown produces a result with a leading space in it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It returns C.

Comment: @jjanes Correct. Works alright without spaces.

Comment: @jjanes. `select greatest(' 5', '0'), length(greatest(' 5', '0')); 5       |      2` or `select greatest('5', '0'), length(greatest('5', '0'));  5        |      1`. Now this is with `show lc_collate; en_US.UTF-8`. So I'm thinking this is collation dependent.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I just want to execute this query anywhere without depending on lc_collate or any such setting. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: You can't at least with strings as their value is determined by the collation. It will be the same behavior as you see with `ORDER BY` on a string value.

Comment: See UPDATE to my answer for example of `ORDER BY` being affected by collation. You can force a collation in a statement, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collation issue:

```
show lc_collate ;
 lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8

select greatest(' 5', '0'), length(greatest(' 5', '0'));
 greatest | length 
----------+--------
  5       |      2

select greatest('5', '0'), length(greatest('5', '0'));
 greatest | length 
----------+--------
 5        |      1

\c c_db

show lc_collate ;
 lc_collate 
------------
 C

select greatest(' 5', '0'), length(greatest(' 5', '0'));
 greatest | length 
----------+--------
 0        |      1
(1 row)

select greatest('5', '0'), length(greatest('5', '0'));
 greatest | length 
----------+--------
 5        |      1


select greatest(' 5'::int, '0'::int);
 greatest 
----------
        5
```

If you stay with `C` collation your choices are:

1. Don't have leading spaces
2. If you know you are always going to be dealing with integer strings then cast to integer.

**UPDATE**

This behavior is due to how the collation affects the sort(value) order of strings. To demonstrate:

```
show lc_collate ;
 lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8

create table str_order(fld_1 varchar);
insert into str_order values ('0'), (' 5');
select * from str_order order by fld_1;
 fld_1 
-------
 0
  5

show lc_collate ;
 lc_collate 
------------
 C
create table str_order(fld_1 varchar);
insert into str_order values ('0'), (' 5');

select * from str_order order by fld_1;
 fld_1 
-------
  5
 0
```

You can force a collation for a given statement:

```
 show lc_collate ;
 lc_collate 
------------
 C

 select greatest((' 5' collate "en_US"), '0'), length(greatest(' 5', '0'));
 greatest | length 
----------+--------
  5       |      1
```

See [Collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) for more information.